# How to read a key pressed by the user and display it on the console?

Tags: c#, console, keyboard

I am trying to ask user "enter any key" and when that key is pressed it shows that "You Pressed 'Key'". Can you help what's wrong in this code?

This is what I have written:

```
using System;
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {      
        Console.Write("Enter any Key: ");
        char name = Console.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("You pressed {0}", name);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the documentation for ConsoleKey it's got a sample doing exactly this (but slightly more advanced): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekey.aspx

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter any Key: ");
ConsoleKeyInfo name = Console.ReadKey();
Console.WriteLine("You pressed {0}", name.KeyChar);
```

Comment: Instead of showing the particular Key in the output, it's giving output as "You pressed System.ConsoleKeyInfo

Comment: Did you change the last line "name" to "name.KeyChar"?

Comment: I changed it and it's fine now, Cheeers!

Answer (score 5):

`Console.Read()` reacts when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and returns the entire string that the user typed before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. To read one keystroke, use

```
Console.ReadKey()
```

Comment: I did as you said and it's giving this error now. "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.ConsoleKeyInfo' to 'char'

Comment: Yes, `Console.ReadKey()` returns a `ConsoleKeyInfo` from which you get the character with `name.KeyChar`, as harriyott shows in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Console.ReadKey()` instead of `Read()`

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.Write("Enter any Key: ");
char name = (char)Console.Read();
Console.WriteLine("You pressed {0}", name);
```

The problem is that Console.Read() returns an integer, not a char.

However, int can be converted to char simply by casting it. Therefore if you put (char) in front of the read statement, C# casts it to a char and it works okay.

Answer (score 0):

```
string keypress = "";

Console.Write("Enter any key: ");
keypress = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("\nYou pressed {0}",keypress);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    Console.Write("Enter any Key: ");
    char name = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("You pressed {0}", name);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use just simple example:
if (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar=='n')
return;