# How do I capture a key press?

Tags: c#, keypress

I am taking programming 2 in school and we are working with Visual Studio 2010 professional.

I am trying to make a game where u can control a character using the arrow keys to move the character for jumping and moving forward and backward.

I have all the graphics all done and set up but I need to be able to make it so that I can control it by using a key to change variables to make the character move and interact with things.

How do you get the program to register a key being pressed?

This is what I have so far:

```
namespace keypress2 
    { 
    public partial class Form1 : Form 
        { 
        public Form1() 
        { 
            InitializeComponent(); 
            this.textBox1.KeyDown += textBox1_KeyDown; 
        } 

        private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
        {

        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: i tried so many things i dont even remember what all i tried

Comment: @BrentClark Hi, and welcome to SO. You need to give us some specific problem that you're having. Assumedly, Visual Studio comes with documentation - if there's something in that which is not clear, ask about that.

Comment: what do you mean documentation??? this is what i have so far                                                                

namespace keypress2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.textBox1.KeyDown += textBox1_KeyDown;
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}

Comment: i dnt know how to do tht thing where it actually shows the cod the way it is. i am new to this site :/

Answer (score 1):

There is a blog item here on handling non-blocking keyboard input in c#

http://www.dutton.me.uk/2009/02/24/non-blocking-keyboard-input-in-c/

also, another stack-overflow article on console keyboard input

[How to read a key pressed by the user and display it on the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068168/c-sharp-keyboard-input-beginner-help)

Of course, I'm making the assumption you are doing a console app. If you are doing a WinForm app, then the answer is different.

Comment: oh sorry i didnt specify tht i am using windows form and i dont even know what i have tried so far. i have tried so many diferent things it isnt even funny :/

Comment: there is an article here on handling key presses: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/ff6b060a-8dc4-4d2c-8dd6-15619de377ee

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "PreviewKeyDown Event" to capture key press.

Let's just say that you want to move your "Hero", which is a Button, inside your Form.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Hero As New Button
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Hero.Parent = Me
        Hero.Enabled = False
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles Me.PreviewKeyDown
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Left
                Hero.Left -= 5
            Case Keys.Right
                Hero.Left += 5
            Case Keys.Down
                Hero.Top += 5
            Case Keys.Up
                Hero.Top -= 5
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

You can also capture other keys like W, A, S, D as an alternative keys to move your character, and Control+S (to save the game). :D

Answer (score 0):

To add events for any controls press F4 to bring up the properties window and click the Lightning Bolt icon:

[image]